# Identify windows computer names using ML

Tags: machine-learning, svm, event-log, naivebayes, computer-name

Windows computer names documentation by Microsoft: https://oofhours.com/2020/11/12/whats-in-a-windows-computer-name/
I want to build an ML model that identifies windows computer names from windows event logs fields.
more about windows event logs fields: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/winlogbeat/6.8/exported-fields-eventlog.html
My questions are:

1. What are the best method to use? I thought about supervised ml & word embedding.
2. Maybe to use Naive-Bayes or SVM?
3. Is it right for me to create a database myself (according to the documentation) that contains values that are machine names and values that are not?

thank's!